# How much blockchain space does it take when installing nodeos on my local desktop computer?

Tags: nodeos

When I download the eos nodeos software for ubuntu, how much space should I have for it to sync to the blockchain and download everything? Bitcoin core takes 250GB. How much does eos take?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My full node running Ubuntu 18.04 and eosio 1.4.1 takes ~105GB.

```
102G    blocks
4.0K    snapshots
3.1G    state
```

If you enable `mongo_db_plugin`, mongodb will cost much more, like 700GB+ for actions only.

Answer (score 0):

currently the block size is about ~65Gb. And there is some db for LIB, and querying actions data. It costs about 2GB, 70GB over each.
hence, total space is about 140GB now and Only for block data is about 65GB

Comment: is there a mode where i don't need to download the entire chain and still use all the eos functions